# Jetpack compose animation clipping problem

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create an animation when the content changes. The problem is that the height of the row changes during the animation, so it jumps up and down, even if I set clipping to false. I'm trying to copy the example from Google that looks like

[image]

**Update:** It seems like it is alignBy(LastBaseline) that is the problem. It works if I remove that.

The composable looks like this:

```
@Composable
fun StatisticsRow() {
    var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Column {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = Modifier.alignBy(LastBaseline).weight(1f)
            ) {
                AnimatedDays(count)
                Text("Days", style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1)
            }
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = Modifier.alignBy(LastBaseline).weight(1f)
            ) {
                Box {
                    val image: Painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_medal_24)
                    Image(painter = image, contentDescription = "")
                }
                Text("Achievements", style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1)
            }
        }
        Button(onClick = { count++ }) { Text("Click me") }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Composable
private fun AnimatedDays(count: Int) {
    AnimatedContent(targetState = count,
        transitionSpec = {
            if (targetState > initialState) {
                slideInVertically({ height -> height }) + fadeIn() with
                        slideOutVertically({ height -> -height }) + fadeOut()
            } else {
                slideInVertically({ height -> -height }) + fadeIn() with
                        slideOutVertically({ height -> height }) + fadeOut()
            }.using(SizeTransform(clip = false))
        }
    ) { targetCount ->
        Text(targetCount.toString(), style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4)
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works if you remove that, then what is the problem?

Comment: When I wrote the question, then I didn't know what the solution was. That's why I updated the post saying that I found out what the problem was. ;)

Comment: Oh. If that's the case, there is an option to 'self-answer' the question. You should answer the question so that others can know that the issue has been resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Mackan, can you share the full code for this up-and-down animation.

Comment: @SreekantShenoy You have the full code in the AnimatedDays function. :) 
MARSK: I will see if I can edit the post and find that "self answer" option.

Comment: Seems like you did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the alignBy(LastBaseline). Remove that and the code works.